# Timezone offset ignored

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-web-api, json.net

When the following setter receives `endDate="2015-05-01T00:00:00+08:00"` in a json string, the time zone offset is lost and the value is `2015-05-01T00:00:00`. I need the date to adjust to UTC when the offset is lost.

The object is deserialized automatically within a WebAPI Formatter using JSON.NET

```
private DateTime? _endDate;
public DateTime? endDate
{
    get {
        //...
    }
    set { _endDate = value; }
}
```

What's wrong or how can I get the UTC time instead?

Comment: What do you get when you do endDate.ToUniversalTime()?

Comment: If you want to work with offsets, there is [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that purpose. Any reason you have to use `DateTime`?

Comment: @DWright You are right. The offset is available, I just didn't see it in the debugging inspector.

Comment: @JesseGood Because the database adapter serializes `DateTimeOffset` in an undesirable way in this case (MongoDB).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your intent would be the following:

```
private DateTime? date;
public DateTime? Date
{
     get
     {
          if(date != null)
               return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertToUtc(date);

          return date;           
     }
}
```

That would create a *Property* that will take a date format, then will convert it to a valid UTC Format.  However, if you require more minute control you'll want to rethink the approach.  You can find more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Hopefully that is what your actually asking, if not I'll delete the answer.